# QLabel "hover" area too small

Tags: qt, hover, label

I'm experiencing a problem with hover functionality on QLabel.
I've implemented this as event filter:

```
HoverLabel::HoverLabel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    installEventFilter(this);

    label = (QLabel *)parent;

    show();
}

bool HoverLabel::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == this)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            label->setText("Howering");
            return true;
        }
        else if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave)
        {
            label->setText("Not howering");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling while main constructor is running as:

```
hoverLabels[0] = new HoverLabel(ui->hoverLabel_1);
```

Now everything works fine except that the area where I ger QEvent::Enter is just too small and what's more, constant - you can double the size of label and area that generates event stays the same.

I've marked the hover area on picture with blue rectangle, as the mouse wasn't captured for whatever reason. Beyond that, it say's "Not howering". I've tried various text content, various text sizes, checking all the boxes around, setting different size policies but the area is still the same.

[image]

Comment: The relation of HoverLabel vs. PlayerLabel isn't clear to me. And why do you create a child widget of the widget in the UI file? It looks to me you create a child widget not inside any layout and expect it to have the dimensions of its parent. Make the event filter object a QObject (not a widget) and install the event filter on ui->hoverLabel_1, not on _this_.

Comment: HoverLabel is just changed name for the sake of minimal sample and now corrected. Anyway beat me to it, I was looking at that piece of code so long it didn't occur to me I'm calling installFilter on wrong object. And I just started using QT, with this method poorly documented I was just experimenting and got some result finally.. but not the right one. You were correct and can make it an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you!! I implemented a hoverable qlabel with the help of your code :)

Comment: @gumlym glad this has helped you. It's always nice to see some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the class had to override eventFilter. In my case class is called PlayerLabel.

See these 2 files for how to:

header file:
https://github.com/metthal/ICP-Projekt/blob/1f0a0f6e919d132bbec6bacd1cff91a3a596460d/inc/gui/mainwindow.h#L40

source file:
https://github.com/metthal/ICP-Projekt/blob/1f0a0f6e919d132bbec6bacd1cff91a3a596460d/src/gui/mainwindow.cpp#L908

Also see how to create this object afterwards:
https://github.com/metthal/ICP-Projekt/blob/1f0a0f6e919d132bbec6bacd1cff91a3a596460d/src/gui/mainwindow.cpp#L358